# peer's txhistory table is not updating after making payment

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I have successfully set up stellar-core in my private network using a different network passphrase with 3 nodes. When I run `stellar-core -c 'info'` output says `state: Synced!`. I have configured one horizon to connect to one of the cores and one client endpoint to communicate with the horizon. Now I want to create 2 accounts in the network and transfer some Lumen from first account to the second account. I am able to create an account without any  issue, a new entry is created in txhistory table of stellar-core database in all 3 nodes. But when I transfer Lumen, txhistory table got updated only in the core in which horizon is connected. Other two nodes does not have any change. Please let me know what i might be doing wrong. Here is my stellar-core.cfg

```
  1 # What port stellar-core listens for commands on. This is for Horizon server.
  2 HTTP_PORT=11626
  3 
  4 PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=false
  5 
  6 # If it is true, It prevents you from trying to connect to other peers
  7 RUN_STANDALONE=false
  8 
  9 # A phrase for your network. All nodes should have the same network phrase.
 10 NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="Standalone Private Network ; Mar 2019"
 11 
 12 # The seed used for generating the public key this node will be identified within SCP.
 13 NODE_SEED="SAUQCRCMMJT5CVTQQKKBTRL25N6NEFRBYIH4KOL6BXVRMLKJ5QNDBEFT self"
 14 
 15 # Only nodes that want to participate in SCP should set NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true.
 16 # Most instances should operate in observer mode with NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=false.
 17 NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true
 18 
 19 # Comma separated peers list
 20 KNOWN_PEERS=[
 21     "192.168.1.7:11625",
 22     "192.168.1.5:11625"
 23 ]
 24 
 25 # Postgres DB URL
 26 DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar_node01_db host=localhost user=node0 password=foo@stellar"
 27 
 28 # The port other instances of stellar-core can connect to you on.
 29 PEER_PORT=11625
 30 
 31 # Log level setup
 32 COMMANDS=["ll?level=trace"]
 33 
 34 FAILURE_SAFETY=0
 35 UNSAFE_QUORUM=true
 36 
 37 #The public keys of the Stellar servers
 38 [QUORUM_SET]
 39 THRESHOLD_PERCENT=100
 40 
 41 # comma sepearted validator list 
 42 VALIDATORS=["$self"]
 43 
 44 [HISTORY.vs]
 45 get="cp /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0} {1}"
 46 put="cp {0} /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{1}"
 47 mkdir="mkdir -p /tmp/stellar-core/history/vs/{0}"
```

Here is the output of `stellar-core -c 'info'`

```
Using DEPRECATED command-line syntax.
Please refer to documentation for new syntax.

2019-03-12T16:02:04.804 <startup> [default INFO] RUN_STANDALONE enabled in configuration file - node will not function properly with most networks
Content-Length: 1046
Content-Type: application/json

2019-03-12T16:02:04.808 GBYOG [default INFO] {
   "info" : {
      "build" : "v10.2.0",
      "history_failure_rate" : "1",
      "ledger" : {
         "age" : 2,
         "baseFee" : 100,
         "baseReserve" : 100000000,
         "closeTime" : 1552386722,
         "hash" : "9d6610c2265ae19889dd18803f2a7b9a58c105e9a80f8b35845d7a0831bbd27c",
         "maxTxSetSize" : 100,
         "num" : 1180,
         "version" : 0
      },
      "network" : "Standalone Private Network ; Mar 2019",
      "peers" : {
         "authenticated_count" : 2,
         "pending_count" : 0
      },
      "protocol_version" : 10,
      "quorum" : {
         "1180" : {
            "agree" : 1,
            "delayed" : 0,
            "disagree" : 0,
            "fail_at" : 0,
            "hash" : "ab248e",
            "missing" : 0,
            "phase" : "EXTERNALIZE",
            "validated" : true
         }
      },
      "startedOn" : "2019-03-12T08:53:47Z",
      "state" : "Synced!",
      "status" : [
         "Publishing 18 queued checkpoints [63-1151]: Succeded: prepare-snapshot"
      ]
   }
}
```